# Update state when a change occurs in a reusable mapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a quizz app with single choice questions , and i have coded this component that i use to map the questions for the quiz making process:

```
const EditableQuestion = ({questionId,correctAnswer,points,text,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, ...otherProps}) => (
    <div className='editable-question'>
        <div className='question-text'>
            <textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder={text}></textarea>
        </div>
        <div className='question-answers'>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio'  name={questionId} defaultChecked={1 === correctAnswer}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans1}/></div>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio'  name={questionId} defaultChecked={2 === correctAnswer}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans2}/></div>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio'  name={questionId} defaultChecked={3 === correctAnswer}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans3}/></div>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio'  name={questionId} defaultChecked={4 === correctAnswer}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans4}/></div>
        </div>
        <div className='points'>
        <input type='text' defaultValue={points}/>
        <span>points</span>
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default EditableQuestion;
```

It works great from what it seems so far, but i do not know how to update the state in order to reflect  the changes that the user does to the mapped questions

My main page looks like this:

```
class QuizEdit extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title : '',
            time : null,
            questionNr : 2,
            questions : [

                {
                    questionId : 1,
                    text : "This is a test question text",
                    ans1 : "Possible answer 1",
                    ans2 : "Possible answer 2",
                    ans3 : "Possible answer 3",
                    ans4 : "Possible answer 4",
                    correctAnswer : 1,
                    points: 5
                },

                {
                    questionId : 2,
                    text : "This is the second test question text",
                    ans1 : "Possible answer 1",
                    ans2 : "Possible answer 2",
                    ans3 : "Possible answer 3",
                    ans4 : "Possible answer 4",
                    correctAnswer : 2,
                    points: 10
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {questions} = this.state;
        return(
            <div className='quiz-edit'>
                <div className='quiz-question'>{
                        questions.map(({questionId,correctAnswer,points,text,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,...otherDraftProps}) => (
                            <EditableQuestion key={questionId} questionId={questionId} text={text} ans1={ans1} ans2={ans2} ans3={ans3} ans4={ans4} correctAnswer={correctAnswer} points={points}{...otherDraftProps}/>
                        ))
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default QuizEdit;
```

The things that i need to update the state with are :

- when the user changes the placeholder for the textarea
- when the user changes the default value in any of the possible answers
- when the user selects another correct answer then the default one
- when the user changes the number of points

I previously used onChange functions, but do not know how to make it work with this complex components. Will it help to have the EditableQuestion component in the same file or it doesnt matter?

Anyways , would love to get some help on how to make this work, thank you all in advance!

Comment: There is no need, to have the EditableQuestion component in the same file, just pass onChange functions, which will manipulate the questions array in parent state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your onChange function something like this

```
handleChange = (value, field, questionId) => {
const questions = [...this.state.questions];
const currentQuestionIndex = questions.findIndex(ques => ques.questionId === questionId);
if (currentQuestionIndex > 0) {
  const newObj = {...questions[currentQuestionIndex], [field]: value.target.value};
questions[currentQuestionIndex] = newObj;
  this.setState({questions})
}
}
```

And in your `EditableQuestion` you need to pass 3 things value, field, questionId like this:

```
<div className='question-text'>
            <textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder={text} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'text', questionId)}></textarea>
        </div>
...
<div className='points'>
        <input type='text' defaultValue={points} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'points', questionId)}/>
        <span>points</span>
        </div>


<div className='question-answers'>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio'  value={1} name={questionId} defaultChecked={1 === correctAnswer} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'correctAnswer', questionId)}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans1}/></div>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio' value={2} name={questionId} defaultChecked={2 === correctAnswer} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'correctAnswer', questionId)}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans2}/></div>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio' name={questionId} defaultChecked={3 === correctAnswer}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans3}/></div>
            <div className='answer'><input type='radio'  name={questionId} defaultChecked={4 === correctAnswer}/><input type='text' defaultValue={ans4}/></div>
        </div>
```

I haven't run this code in text editor. So correct if there's any lint errors or paste the error.

Comment: Hello there, i updated the code with your idea, but when i type anything in the textarea / text input i get an error from the handleChange function that says `TypeError: questions.find is not a function`

Comment: Oh sorry! My bad. I have destructured questions into an object instead of array. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that works now, but now in the render function i get this : `TypeError: questions.map is not a function`

Comment: Arrh. Again, same mistake. Updated answer

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much , but now , on the setState from handleChange function it says : `TypeError: currentQuestion is not iterable`

Comment: No, thats ok. Can u console currentQuestion and show the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235663/discussion-between-neel-dsouza-and-masterwilliams).